# How can I update the nested array stored in firebase database in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase

i want to update commentText array but when i code like that it doesn't work

here is my code

```
firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByChild("creatorId").equalTo(creatorId).on("child_added", (data) => {
   data.ref.update({
        comments: data.val().comments.commentText.concat(this.input)
    })
}
```

see image here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `creatorId` property is under the `comments` node, so you need to order/filter on `comments/creatorId`:

```
firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByChild("comments/creatorId").equalTo(creatorId).on("child_added", (data) => {
   data.ref.update({
        comments: data.val().comments.commentText.concat(this.input)
    })
})
```

---

Old answer below, since the code might still be useful.

<strike>When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.</strike>

So your code needs to handle this list, even if there's only one result:

```
firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByChild("creatorId").equalTo(creatorId).once("value", (snapshot) => {
   snapshot.forEach((data) => {
      data.ref.update({
         comments: data.val().comments.commentText.concat(this.input)
      })
   })
}
```

Comment: the creatorId is not under the comments node

Comment: Sorry about that. In that case I'm not sure why it doesn't work. If you put a breakpoint on the `data.ref.update(` line and run in a debugger, does it hit that breakpoint? Also: if you hard-code the value of `creatorId` in the call to `equalTo` does it work? If not, can you update the code in your question to reflect that change (as right now we can't see what value/type `creatorId` has).